# How to draw a proper directed graph with negative weights of edges using python module networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I want to draw directed graphs with negative weights of edges using networkx & matplotlib.pyplot.

Here is my method:

```
def show(self):
    # self._g is object of nx.DiGraph()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(self._g)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(self._g, pos, node_size=500)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(self._g, pos, width=2.0, arrowsize=20)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(self._g, pos, font_size=8)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(self._g, pos)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

And it looks like this (turns straight line or something indescribable):

[image: screenshoot]

Without edges with negative weights:

[image: screenshoot#2]

I know there is other layouts but they don't look good. Is there any way to draw good-looking directed graph with negative edges in networkx

Comment: Please add a complete code example to help answer your question (the class, _g, pos, ...). And what do you mean by negative edges? The weights? The position?

Comment: What would a negative edge look like?

Comment: Updated. Sorry for inaccurate description. But I don't think code of my class matters. There is no references to external structures except of self._g.

Comment: Having a reproducible and complete example *does* matter, because it means other people can run your code to try and troubleshoot. And you are going to have to clarify what you mean by a 'negative edge' or 'negative weights'. Perhaps you can include this in your complete and verifiable example code?

Comment: A negative weight in `spring_layout` will act as a repelling force between two nodes. Hence your graph ends up being stretched. For the purpose of the layout, I would convert negative edges to positive ones.